# Stream search - legality

Tags: search-engines, legal

I would like to know  if **it is worth asking a lawyer about** making a search engine that indexes sites which index mega video links which contain movies that are protected by copyright law is legal.

Specifically:

- Do you believe it is ethically justifiable, from your point of view. I.e. if you knew legally it was o.k. would you do it?
- Do you know of anyone which asked a lawyer on a similar topic and if so was the lawyer able to give a definitive answer?
- Would you ever consider making a website of the kind and consult a lawyer or would you deem it immediately to be a grey and ambiguous area you wish not to be in.

Answers should build on the facts that:

- I have already finished coding a large part (still some bugs) I have therefore invested a faire amount of time
- Dropping the project is an option I can live with

Thanking you in advance,

Flyingswissman

Comment: You need to ask a lawyer, there's no way anybody here can ask this for you, especially as the laws differ vastly from country to country. In some places it's decriminalised, but still illegal, in others they will come after each and every individual user. **Ask a lawyer**.

Comment: I totally agree with you. However, I'm only asking for subjective and personal opinion from people. Also people who have made websites in this area. I'm just interested what peoples intuition is so I can get a feel for the general opinion. I'm not asking for a definitive answer which I can absolutely depend on. I think that answers could actually be of global value. I ask you to consider reopening the question to answers.

Comment: @Flyingswissman, your latest comment seems to contradict your latest post edit - did you mean to say, "I do **not** expect a definitive answer [...]", in your main post?

Comment: Flyingswissman said: "I do expect a definitive, jurisdictionally correct and educated answer, one which could be expected of a lawyer." Then go find (and pay) a lawyer.

Comment: @songdogtech, but then his *comment* says, "I'm **not** asking for a definitive answer" - I think he *left out a word* in the main post (thus leading to mis-interpretation). Then again, maybe he does just have really *high standards*, for answers supplied by random strangers on the Internet... :/

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally omitted a crucial "not"... I hope its obvious I appreciate any help I can get and certainly do not expect information from strangers to be of high standard. So back to the topic: Does anyone have any pointers, suggestions, hints  (of subjective nature) for me?

Comment: Flyingswissman: You're continuing to be naive. You "do not expect information from strangers to be of high standard," yet you are asking a question of a legal nature that will have legal ramifications on what you want to do. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5533/proposal-for-a-law-se for the numerous issues asking internet strangers for legal advice.

Comment: @songdogtech: Answers will not have legal ramifications. The only consequence it will have is either I ask a lawyer or I don't (and bury the idea). I'm wondering if the question is worth a lawyer. Now you might say that's a question only I can answer. But I believe  some people are capable of putting themselves in my situation as they have been in similar situations or know of people that have been.